# how to check that extension methods on an array got a specific size?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using extension methods based on an array and I would like to know if there is an easy way to check that array got a specify size instead of me doing a copy paste of

```
   if array.count != 1000
      throw new exception "size of the array does not match"
```

in about ~50 extensions

this a small sample of extensions that I use, I got WAY more

```
<Extension()>
Public Function IsWhite(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.White) = bitPiece.White
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsBlack(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Black) = bitPiece.Black
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsRook(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Rook) = bitPiece.Rook
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsBishop(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Bishop) = bitPiece.Bishop
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsKnight(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.knight) = bitPiece.knight
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsQueen(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Queen) = bitPiece.Queen
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsKing(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.King) = bitPiece.King
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function IsPawn(ByVal board() As bitPiece, ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Pawn) = bitPiece.Pawn
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean "extensions"?

Comment: this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: OK, then use the term, "extension methods".  It's still not clear to me what you are looking for.  Throw those two lines in a common static method if you want to reuse the logic.  Am I missing something?

Comment: text/title fixed with "extension methods", thing is I would like a "generic" way of checking the array without having to do a huge amount of copy/paste

Comment: Do you think you could post say two of your extension methods so that we can talk about this in a more realistic setting?  (I assume you're not actually checking against `1000`)

Comment: I added a few example, I have maybe 10x that amount of extensions, I want to make sure the board always have a size of 64

Comment: I don't see why the size of the board would change at all in the examples you listed -- they don't modify state.  Furthermore, if `pos` is out of bounds, wouldn't whatever collection you're using already throw an exception?

Comment: @Fredou: BTW are you sure your actually need all these methods? A chess board field can usually only hold one piece, so I don't see why you need to bitfield here. Instead of calling `IsKing(pos)` a consumer could simply do `Get(pos) == bitPiece.Kind`.

Comment: @dtb, because of my implementation the board(pos) can tell if it's also white or  black or of the piece has moved and other informations, in bitwise operation, so a direct == would not work

Comment: @Fredou: Direct == works if `Get(pos)` returns `board(pos) And (bitPiece.Pawn Or bitPiece.King Or bitPiece.Queen Or ...)`

Comment: @dtb, I just tried it, it doesnt work, not the best place to do this but anyway ;-) c is false,    [Flags()]
    enum test
    {
        white = 1,
        king = 2
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test t = test.white | test.king;
            bool c = t == test.white;
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your array is not really an array but represents a specific data structure (a chess board), have you considered creating a dedicated type for it?

```
class Board
{
    private readonly bitPiece[] board;

    public Board()
    {
        board = new bitPiece[64];
    }

    Public Function IsBlack(ByVal pos As Integer) As Boolean
        Return (board(pos) And bitPiece.Black) = bitPiece.Black
    End Function
}
```

Comment: Ha, nice surgery there with the C#/VB mashup. ;)  But good answer.

Comment: hmmm I could try to see if I could do something like this, in my case it would be more a partial class board :-p

Comment: but, does a "generic validation" check can be done on extensions? could be good to know for future use

Comment: @Fredou: If you want to have something checked in each method, then there is no way around inserting at least 1 line of code into each method. You can avoid this problem by ensuring that the array has the right size when creating it, and preventing other arrays to be passed in.

Comment: I was hoping it would be possible without having to  do this because while looking at it, i also need to check pos, it need to be in >= 0 and <= 63

Comment: @Fredou: The array will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException if the index is outside the bounds. If this is acceptable for you (the proper way would be to throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException) then you don't need to insert an extra check.

Comment: true, i might be going overboard with all these checks

Comment: in the end, long time ago, i went with the 0x88 chessboard representation

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like:

```
public static void CheckArrLength(this double[] x, int length)
    {
        if (x.Length != length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Array Size."); 
    }
```

And every method can just call it like this:

```
public static void Func(this double[] x)
    {
        x.CheckArrLength(1000);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want something like:

```
public static void AssertLength<T>(this T[] arr, int expectedLength)
{
    if (arr == null || arr.Length != expectedLength)
    {
        throw new Exception("Size of the array does not match");
    }
}
```

which you can call using

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.AssertLength(5);
```

Comment: `ArgumentException` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, a more specific exception type would be better, I just based it on the example in the question.

Comment: is there an easy way to attach that to make a validation check on the array, look at my question I updated it